# Grant access to a different user's home directory

Tags: centos, permissions, home

I've created a user that's locked down to it's home directory and does nothing else but allow a client to upload an ftp file to us - hands slightly tied at the moment regarding that, so I've had to do it.

I don't want to use this new `ftpuser` for anything else at all, I'd rather use a different user, `myuser` that handles other data imports.

So I've made `myuser` part of the `ftpuser` group and set the `/home/ftpuser` folder to 775 and `chrgrp myuser` but I still can't access the contents of the folder.

```
$ pwd
/home

$ ls -la
total 44
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root       root        4096 Jun 13 10:48 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 23 root       root        4096 May 18 11:41 ..
drwxrwx---   2 ftpuser    myuser      4096 Jul 12 16:47 ftpuser
drwx------  14 myuser     myuser      4096 Jun 29 17:08 myuser

$ ls ftpuser/
ls: cannot open directory ftpuser/: Permission denied

$ ls myuser/
bin tmp vhosts

$ id myuser
uid=502(myuser) gid=503(www-data) groups=503(www-data),505(ftpuser)
```

Do home folders have some additional restrictions on them that stop me doing this, or am I missing something obvious?

I'm on CentOS 6.5

Comment: Try either logging out and logging back in, or using the `newgrp` command.

Comment: `newgrp` is probably your best bet. The primary group on `myuser` is `www-data` so it needs to be switched to one of the supplementary groups after login.

Comment: I hadn't even noticed that `myuser` is not even listed as a group when I run `id` - why does the `myuser` folder have that as it's group in that case?

Comment: also the `newgrp` thing totally fixed it... so someone should answer so I can accept, not sure if I can accept you both

Answer (score 1):

```
drwxrwx---   2 ftpuser    myuser      4096 Jul 12 16:47 ftpuser
uid=502(myuser) gid=503(www-data) groups=503(www-data),505(ftpuser)
```

the group on the dir is myuser, and myuser does not have group myuser, but it has ftpuser.

Fix with either:

```
usermod -a -G myuser myuser
```

or (preferred so files created by ftpuser also have the same group as you):

```
chgrp ftpuser /home/ftpuser
```

Also, make sure the ftp daemon is using a mask that allows group to have read access, such as `local_umask=007` or `local_umask=027` in vsftpd.conf.